# Конвейер обработки запросов ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

Привет всем! Где можно найти наиболее подробную схему или описание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://www.msdr.ru/files/ASP.NET MVC 3 Pipeline.pdf](http://www.msdr.ru/files/ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Pipeline.pdf)

Comment: Спасибо, вроде то что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/62694/) есть неплохое описание.